# batch script - replace multiple arguments in a file at the same time

Tags: string, file, batch-file, replace

The file to be modified is located in each directory of several users (%user%), ex: `D:\Folder2\Userlist\user\config.yml`

It’s called `config.yml`, looks like this:

```yaml
#module1: [ var1 ]
#module2: [ var2 ]
#module3: [ var3 ]
#module4: [ var4 ]
```

My goal being from the command line, to be able to activate a module by raising the `#` and replacing the `var` by a choice in my script like this:

```yaml
#module1: [ var1 ]
#module2: [ var2 ]
module3: [ something ]
#module4: [ var4 ]
```

Or desactivate it by correcting the `#`

```yaml
#module1: [ var1 ]
#module2: [ var2 ]
#module3: [ something ]
#module4: [ var4 ]
```

I have two files based in a directory, `D:\Folder\Example`

**TEST.BAT**

```bash
GOTO CHOOSEACCOUNT & exit

:CHOOSEACCOUNT
set "accountpath=D:\Folder2\Userlist"
CLS
ECHO.
dir /b /s %accountpath%\*.yml
ECHO.
SET /P "user=Choose a config?"
GOTO UPDATELINKCONFIG

:UPDATELINKCONFIG
if exist "%accountpath%\%user%\config.yml" (
    set "pathuser=%accountpath%\%user%\config.yml"
    GOTO CHOOSETASK
) else (
    START cmd.exe /k "Color 4 && echo User Config don't exist ... && timeout /t 3 && exit"
    GOTO CHOOSEACCOUNT
)

:CHOOSETASK
CLS
ECHO.
ECHO path loaded: %pathuser%
ECHO account: %user%
ECHO.
TYPE %accountpath%\%user%\config-update.txt #TO PRINT ALL CHANGES
echo   +--------+
echo   ^| MENU ^|
echo   +--------+
ECHO.
ECHO   1 -  EXAMPLE1
ECHO   2 -  EXAMPLE2
ECHO   3 -  EXAMPLE3
ECHO   4 -  EXAMPLE4
ECHO   5 -  EXAMPLE5
ECHO   6 -  EXAMPLE6
ECHO   7 -  EXIT
ECHO.
ECHO.
SET /P "C4=CHOOSE AND PRESS ENTER: "
IF %C4%==1 GOTO EXAMPLE1
IF %C4%==2 GOTO EXAMPLE2
IF %C4%==3 GOTO EXAMPLE3
IF %C4%==4 GOTO EXAMPLE4
IF %C4%==5 GOTO EXAMPLE5
IF %C4%==6 GOTO EXAMPLE6
IF %C4%==7 GOTO EXIT
START cmd.exe /k "Color 4 && echo Wrong option ... && timeout /t 3 && exit"
GOTO CHOOSETASK

:EXAMPLE1
SET /P "id90=WHO IS THE USER TO PUT? (syntax: username1, username2)"
CLS
ECHO.
echo   +---------+
echo   ^| SUBMENU ^|
echo   +---------+
ECHO.
ECHO   1 -  MODULE1
ECHO   2 -  MODULE2
ECHO   3 -  MODULE3
ECHO   4 -  MODULE4
ECHO   5 -  GO BACK
ECHO.
ECHO.
SET /P "C5=CHOOSE AND PRESS ENTER: "
IF %C5%==1 set "search=var1" && set "replace=%id90%" && set "module=module1" && GOTO ACTIVATEDESA
IF %C5%==2 set "search=var2" && set "replace=%id90%" && set "module=module2" && GOTO ACTIVATEDESA
IF %C5%==3 set "search=var3" && set "replace=%id90%" && set "module=module3" && GOTO ACTIVATEDESA
IF %C5%==4 set "search=var4" && set "replace=%id90%" && set "module=module4" && GOTO ACTIVATEDESA
IF %C5%==5 GOTO CHOOSETASK
CLS
START cmd.exe /k "Color 4 && echo Wrong option ... && timeout /t 3 && exit"
GOTO CHOOSETASK

:ACTIVATEDESA
CLS
set "moduleactivation=%module%"
set "moduledesactivation=#%module%"
ECHO.
ECHO   1 -  Activate
ECHO   2 -  Desactivate
ECHO.
ECHO.
SET /P "C11=CHOOSE AND PRESS ENTER: "
IF %C11%==1 GOTO ACTIVATEMODULE
IF %C11%==2 GOTO DESACTIVATEMODULE
CLS
START cmd.exe /k "Color 4 && echo Wrong option ... && timeout /t 3 && exit"
GOTO CHOOSETASK

:ACTIVATEMODULE
set s1=%moduledesactivation%
set r1=%moduleactivation%
START cmd.exe /k "D:\Folder\Example\update.bat && timeout /t 3 && exit"
(
echo The option %module% has been activated ^!
)>>"%accountpath%\%user%\config-update.txt"
timeout /t 2
set s1=%search%
set r1=%replace%
START cmd.exe /k "D:\Folder\Example\update.bat && timeout /t 3 && exit"
(
echo The module %module% parameter has been updated of %search% to %replace% ^!
)>>"%accountpath%\%user%\config-update.txt"
GOTO CHOOSETASK

:DESACTIVATEMODULE
set s1=%moduleactivation%
set r1=%moduledesactivation%
START cmd.exe /k "D:\Folder\Example\update.bat && timeout /t 3 && exit"
(
echo The option %module% has been desactivated ^!
)>>"%accountpath%\%global%\config-update.txt"
GOTO CHOOSETASK

:EXIT
exit
```

I had to shorten the code to keep everything clear but there are several `:EXAMPLE` functions.

**UPDATE.BAT**

```bash
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
call: D:\Folder\Example\test.bat

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('type "%pathuser%" ^& break ^> "%pathuser%" ') do (
    set "line=%%i"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    >>"%pathuser%" echo(!line:%s1%=%r1%!
    endlocal
    ) 

exit /b
```

This script reads the file in `%pathuser%`, replaces the string `%search%` with `%replace%`, and saves the file without creating another output. (this saves me from delete/move/rename)

**Everything is functional, however I have a few questions,**

1. When I want to activate 2 times a change in `:ACTIVATEMODULE`, everything works, but I have an error in my cmd pages while everything worked:

> ```
> the system cannot find the command file name -
> ```

2. Would it be possible to integrate the `update.bat` file directly into `test.bat`, with a `call: UPDATE arg1 arg2`? I don’t fully understand the concept with `%~1`, `%~2` ect... This will allow me to have only one file
3. When for example `var1` is changed into something, if I want to relaunch a change again, it does not work since `var1` no longer exists. Would it be possible to store the variable and thus change `set "search=var1"` to `set "search=%var1%"`. Or to put a variable `%var1%`, for example, instead of a character string `var1` to be able to dynamically change the value?